# Sudo "/usr/sbin/halt", "/usr/sbin/reboot", "/usr/sbin/poweroff" - how to leverage it to privilege escalation?

Tags: linux, privilege-escalation

A normal user can execute these commands as root without providing any password (sudo includes the full path of the command so path hijack isn't the case here), could "halt", "reboot", or "poweroff" be leveraged to escalate the users' privileges to root?

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about the setup? You mention `sudo` - does this mean the files are in `sudoers`? Or are they `setuid` like the answer suggests?

Comment: @domen very good point, I read "A normal user can execute these commands as root" and saw the words "path hijack" and "escalate ... privileges" and totally missed the part about `sudo` and just assumed it was setuid :p answer updated

Comment: There's nothing about any of these on gtfobins

Answer (score 1):

The ability to invoke as root is not a property of the *names* `halt`, `reboot`, or `poweroff`, but of the *files* that are executed. The setuid bit is a file permission bit that means whenever you try to execute the given file, it is run with the permissions of whoever owns it (in the case of `su`, `sudo`, `halt`, `reboot`, and `poweroff`, root). You cannot use mucking about with `$PATH` to, say, make `halt` point to your own executable that gets invoked as root—if you hope to abuse setuid for privilege escalation, you *must* find a bug in an already-extant setuid program on the system (which is precisely why setuid program bugs are considered utterly critical).

EDIT: Seeing a comment on the question has made me reevaluate what the question means, and realise the following may be better suited as an answer:

If you've configured `/etc/sudoers` to allow normal users invocation of an **absolute path only** (as you have in fact done), then whether or not users can muck with the `$PATH` that `sudo` calls on (according to the manpage, changes to `$PATH` pass through `sudo` to the executed command unless the security policy resets it, although the default security policy does), they cannot invoke arbitrary binaries named `halt`, `reboot`, or `poweroff`, since you specified a unique path. Once again, only if those binaries themselves can be exploited, can someone cause trouble—but the attack surface is much bigger if you're allowing the execution of a binary that wasn't originally made to be setuid. You should make sure your `/etc/sudoers` security policy resets environment variables, to limit the range of attack (and prevent, e.g., abuse of a `sudo`'d shell script which uses the `$PATH`)—by default it does if you haven't tampered with the `env_reset` flag. You can double-check by setting some environment variables, including `$PATH`, and doing `sudo env` to print all the environment variables a program run by `sudo` gets.

Comment: There's a an important point to make about *they cannot invoke arbitrary binaries named halt, reboot, or poweroff, since you specified a unique path* - while true for these on my system, many binaries provide an easy way to escape to shell (e.g. vim, mysql, man), which might not be obvious to person configuring `sudoers`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be simple. Just like how you're doing privilege escalation by using cronjobs. You find a writable file and put your payload in then wait.

`sudo -l` gives "/usr/sbin/halt", "/usr/sbin/reboot", "/usr/sbin/poweroff" that means one thing here. You can reboot the machine as ROOT.

So, you need to look for some writable configuration files that trigger when start/reboot. `find . -writable` on `/etc` or just run `linpeas`.

The file is most likely owned by root. But read and writable in our favour. e.g.

```
ls -lh /etc/systemd/system/some.service
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root rob /etc/systemd/system/some.service
```

Maybe the file is running by root, then you find the exec line add `ExecXXX: you evil payload here`.

Or change the runner of it if that's not triggered by root in default. `User: low_level_user -> root`